# How to create JQuery Modal Login Box in C#

Tags: c#, jquery

Please guide me to develop Login Modal Popup using JQuery and C#.

When User will click on "Login" link on the page, it will show the modal popup which will be having username and password fields and "login", "Cancel" button, it should also validate the fields for validations and if required entry is done it should send ajax https web request to validate the valid user and if it returns false then it should show the message in the modal popup only., if user login is valid then it should close the modal popup form.

Please suggest as it is very new to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Popup -> [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)
2. Ajax -> [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You can check live example [here](http://ajeva.com/). 'Sign in' link at the left top part of the screen.

Comment: Thanks but how can I download the code for the live example you have given